# Not able to install magenta-gpu

Tags: python, pip, magenta

Running this command to install magenta-gpu:

`pip install magenta-gpu --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver`

and seeing this following error:

```
Collecting optax (from flax>=0.2.0->dopamine-rl->tensor2tensor>=1.13.4->magenta-gpu)
  Using cached optax-0.1.4-py3-none-any.whl (154 kB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement orbax-checkpoint (from flax>=0.2.0->dopamine-rl->tensor2tensor>=1.13.4->magenta-gpu) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for orbax-checkpoint (from flax>=0.2.0->dopamine-rl->tensor2tensor>=1.13.4->magenta-gpu)
```

The using of "--use-deprecated" option is because there was an "Error: metadata-generation-failed" while running the original installing command:

```
Collecting orbax (from flax>=0.2.0->dopamine-rl->tensor2tensor>=1.13.4->magenta-gpu)
  Using cached orbax-0.1.8.tar.gz (1.6 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [3 lines of output]
      
      *** Orbax is a namespace, and not a standalone package. For model checkpointing and exporting utilities, please install `orbax-checkpoint` and `orbax-export` respectively (instead of `orbax`). ***
      
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
```

So does that "--use" option work? If it does, then how to fix that "cannot find a version" error?

Just like what I mentioned above...